# How to read a specific CSV file with user input?

Tags: java, input

I have this little code that gets 2 inputs from the user which are month(int) and Police region(String).  After the user select the CSV file, i want to store the data in array list.  The problem i got now is that when i type for example month [02] and policing operation [merseyside] i do not get the specific file but the next one or random.

CSV files format is like:

- 2018-02-cheshire-stop-and-search.csv
- 2018-02-merseyside-stop-and-search.csv
- 2018-03-cheshire-stop-and-search.csv
- 2018-03-merseyside-stop-and-search.csv
- 2018-04-cheshire-stop-and-search.csv
- 2018-04-merseyside-stop-and-search.csv

  ```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.io.IOException;



  public class ImportData {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

          File f = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\Coursework\\src");   
          File[] fileList = f.listFiles(); 

          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
          System.out.println("Enter month: ");
          int month = input.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter Police region: ");
          String region = input.next();

          input.close();

          try {
              File af = new File(fileList[month].getCanonicalPath());
              System.out.println(af.toString());

              for(int i = 0; i<fileList.length;i++) {
                      String fname=fileList[month].getCanonicalPath();
                      if (fname.contains(region)) {



                              //deal with file;

              }
          else {
                  //write error message
          }   
          }
        }
              catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
  }   
      }
  ```

Comment: Nothing related to `csv` files, nor `array-list`. It;s related how to choose the file regarding the user input.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I have changed now.

Comment: `String fname=fileList[month].getCanonicalPath();` -> should this be `String fname=fileList[**i**].getCanonicalPath();`?

Comment: Yeah thats fine. Thank you.